# Highcharts space usage

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have the following problem. If no max value is defined Highcharts always adds space at the end of the bar. To illustrate it I've attached a image. The  blue area is the div the chart is inside and I want the bars with 100% end on the end of the blue area. I'm aware of it that I can achive this by setting max:1 on the axis but I'm looking for a dynamic approach since when I'm defining max it is fixed and if the maximum value in the Chart is 80% I again end up with unused space.

Thanks Sebastian

[image: Bar Chart]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set max as 100 for yAxis, not 1.

EDIT:

set `maxPadding` as 0 and `endOnTick` as true

http://jsfiddle.net/Km8CK/4/

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.maxPadding
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.endOnTick

Comment: I should mention that the values are 0.01 - 1 and are formatted as percent. But as I already mentioned this would be to inflexible for my purposes

Comment: Yes I know, but if I have set it to 1 and the maximum value would be 0.8 the scale won't adjust anymore.

Comment: Now it is more clear for me, so set maxPadding as 0 and endOnTick as true.

Answer (score 0):

Set your maxPadding to 0, and endOnTick to false.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/Km8CK/6/

```
maxPadding:0,
endOnTick:false,
```